# How to deal with slow load page in nextjs when using getInitialProps?

Tags: reactjs, performance, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using `nextjs 9` and `redux`.Here is a page of my app :

```
import React from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { ShowDataCmp } from '../../components';
import { getData } from '../../store/SamplePage/SamplePageAction';

const SamplePage = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    return <ShowDataCmp query={router.query} />;
};

SamplePage.getInitialProps = async ({ store }) => {
    const config = {
        start_date: '1991-10-22',
        end_date: '2019-10-22',
    };
    await store.dispatch(
        getData(config),
    );
};

export default SamplePage;
```

I want to fetch some data and `dispatch an action` to store the data in `redux`.

I then use the data in `ShowDataCmp`.I need it to be Server side so that the data would be in the pagesourse so I have to get the data here. But because my fetch API is a little bit slow the page load will be really slow.

Are there any solutions to compensate the page slow load time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to implement a loading screen in your `_app` page or `layout` component and optimize `getData` function